# Run PowerShell command using CSV

Tags: powershell, import, export-to-csv

I have been having an issue and have not been able to resolve this for some time now. What I am trying to do is the following:

- using PowerShell export the names of files in within a folder to a CSV.
  My command:

  ```
  dir ‘test 2’ | select-object ‘Name’ 2>&1 > output.csv
  ```
- it creates the the output.csv
- I then want to be able to take the items from the CSV and set a classification. I know i have to import the list. My command:

  ```
  $csv = Import-Csv \\Server\user\folder\output.csv $csv.Name |
         ForEach-Object { $_ “hello” }
  foreach ($line in $csv) {
      Set-Classification -TextLabel "Internal" $line.Name -UseADSMarking -PreserveTimestamps –SetUpdateMarkings
  }
  ```
- there may be thousands of different files that may or may not have a classification on a file. I was looking for an easy way to filter out items and import the list back in then run it as a command.

Examples folder

```
folder > doc
folder > xls
folder > eml
folder > docx
folder > doc 2
folder > doc 3
```

Examples working script to classify

```
Set-Classification -FileList 'z:\Sort\Overview.pdf','z:\Sort\Scenarios.xlsx','z:\Sort\Phase.eml','z:\Sort\Diagrams.docx' -UseADSMarking -PreserveTimestamps -SetUpdateMarkings
```

Comment: [1] where does `Set-Classification` come from? it is not a standard cmdlet AND is not listed at the MSDocs site. [*grin*] ///// [2] why are you redirecting the error stream into the output stream? ///// [3] why are you not using the `Export-CSV` cmdlet to create your `Output.csv` file?

Comment: Please explain what isn't working the way you expected.

Comment: Set-Classification is from the boldon james classifier tool.

Comment: I am still new to this powershell so im willing to try anything. what is not working = once i get the export and i have the filenames in the csv, i am not sure how to create a script and use the filename as part of the script for each line.

 example:
file.docx

script example:(i have to use Set-Classification)
Set-Classification -FileList 'z:\Sort\(INSERT FILENAME HERE FROM CSV.docx' -UseADSMarking -PreserveTimestamps -SetUpdateMarkings

Comment: I think that i had over thought this: my solution:

        dir 'test 2' | export-csv '\\SERVER\user\FOLDER\test 2\export.csv' -NoTypeInformation

then i took the csv and made some formulas.

        dir "Full Name" | Set-Classification -TextLabel "Internal" 2>&1 > output.log -UseADSMarking -PreserveTimestamps -SetUp
dateMarkings